# iOS 5 Back Button Size

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationitem, uiappearance

I'm using the iOS 5 [UIAppearance protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to use a custom navigation bar back button as seen [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5). Unlike other methods I've found, this one is the best since it preserves the default back button animations and behaviours.

The only problem is that I can't change its **size** or set it to **not clip subviews**. Here's what's happening:

[image: Clipping Image]

A is intended behaviour, B is default style, C is the clipped result.

Unfortunately, it's not as easy as setting UIBarButtonItem to clipsToBounds=NO.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried UIBarButtonItem.superview.clipsToBounds = NO? (Or superview.superview...)
Because the navigation bar is not intended to be larger than it is already. So anything you'll try will be a 'hack'. And if it is a hack, then this is the 'standard' way to go :-)

Comment: What you are recommending is not possible since `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't inherit from `UIView`. However, I have tried setting     `self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.customView.clipsToBounds = NO;` and `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.customView.clipsToBounds = NO;`. I assume you meant that the `UIBarButtonItem` is not intended to be larger as I'm not touching the nav bar itself.

Comment: Yes you are right! What I generally mean is traversing the view hierarchy and finding out which one clips. Also you may have to take care of iOS < 5 and iOS >=5 differently.
I actually mean the the navigation bar isn't meant to be larger, because the bar items are not limited, the navigation bar is what limits them. It has hardcoded padding and the leftover is the space for the buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've discovered, `UIAppearance` proxies won't let you adjust the dimensions of the button itself: the list of supported appearance methods for `UIBarButtonItem` is given in the documentation, and whilst it includes metrics for the title label itself the button is off-limits.

For what it's worth, the button itself is actually 44 pts (88 pixels, if you're in retina) high in terms of touchable area, it's just the button *graphic* is smaller than that.

If you're dead set on what amounts to a 3 pt difference in height then the best option is probably going to be to create your own custom button and use the `UINavigationItem` `setLeftBarButtonItem` method. As you point out, you're going to need to implement a short method attached to that button that implements `popNavigationController` to ensure the correct behavior remains.

**Update**: I've just found out that if you keep your back button around you can, in fact, animate it to have it slide in a similar fashion to a standard back button. In the code below `self.backButton` is the `UIButton` you would have used in your `initWithCustomView` `UIBarButtonItem` method.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
                     animations:^{
                         self.backButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.backButton.frame.origin.x+100, 
                                                            self.backButton.frame.origin.y, 
                                                            self.backButton.frame.size.width, 
                                                            self.backButton.frame.size.height);
                     }];
}
```

...this will trigger whenever the view controller disappears (ie, when popped *and* pushed), but you could hook into the `UINavigationController` delegate to only trigger it when the nav controller is popped instead. It definitely seems to move the button when controller is pushed, although I've only tested it on the simulator.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions about `UIAppearance`, @lxt. Unfortunately, by setting a custom `leftBarButtonItem`, I lose the `backBarButtonItem` animation (horizontal sliding) and since `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't inherit from `UIView`, I can't animate it myself.

Comment: Try the code I just posted, might help you with the animation. Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a custom view controller class for every VC I'm using in my navigation controller.

**OEViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "OEBarButtonItem.h"

@interface OEViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *backButton;
@property (atomic) BOOL pushed;

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController*)vc;

@end
```

**OEViewController.m**

```
#import "OEViewController.h"

#define ANIMATION_DURATION 0.33

@implementation OEViewController
@synthesize backButton, pushed;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    pushed=YES;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

    backButton = [OEBarButtonItem backButtonWithTitle:[(UIViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[self.navigationController.viewControllers count]-2] title]];

    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (pushed) {
        self.backButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.backButton.frame.origin.x+100, 
                                           self.backButton.frame.origin.y+6, 
                                           self.backButton.frame.size.width, 
                                           self.backButton.frame.size.height);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION 
                         animations:^{
                             self.backButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.backButton.frame.origin.x-100, 
                                                                self.backButton.frame.origin.y, 
                                                                self.backButton.frame.size.width, 
                                                                self.backButton.frame.size.height);
                         }];
        pushed=NO;
    } else {
        self.backButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.backButton.frame.origin.x-100, 
                                           self.backButton.frame.origin.y, 
                                           self.backButton.frame.size.width, 
                                           self.backButton.frame.size.height);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION 
                         animations:^{
                             self.backButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.backButton.frame.origin.x+100, 
                                                                self.backButton.frame.origin.y, 
                                                                self.backButton.frame.size.width, 
                                                                self.backButton.frame.size.height);
                         }];
    }
}

- (void)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION 
                     animations:^{
                         self.backButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.backButton.frame.origin.x+100, 
                                                            self.backButton.frame.origin.y, 
                                                            self.backButton.frame.size.width, 
                                                            self.backButton.frame.size.height);
                     }];
}

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController*)vc {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION 
                     animations:^{
                         self.backButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.backButton.frame.origin.x-100, 
                                                            self.backButton.frame.origin.y, 
                                                            self.backButton.frame.size.width, 
                                                            self.backButton.frame.size.height);
                     }];
}

@end
```

This has the added benefit of working with iOS 4.0+ as opposed to using UIAppearance.

Thanks to @lxt for his help!